# What is the difference between "ADD KEY" and "ADD INDEX" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, key, alter-table

I dump database and i have one question. What does this query?

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_cart_rule` ADD KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`,`active`,`date_to`);
ALTER TABLE `ps_cart_rule` ADD KEY `id_customer_2` (`id_customer`,`active`,`highlight`,`date_to`);
```

What is diffrence between **ADD KEY** and **ADD INDEX**?

Comment: Please read the ALTER TABLE documentation. If you still did not understand, do let us know.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`.

> ...   | ADD {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] ...

Check the MySQL documentation for [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: I saw that but i didn't know what INDEX|KEY means. Now it's claar, thanx!

Comment: Glad to hear! You can accept the answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: The claim here is true but the quote from the docs in no way supports it. The MySQL docs use `{foo|bar|baz}` syntax in contexts where `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are *not* synonymous all the time, including on the very same page you've linked to.